# How can I pass two parameters from ActionLink to ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm implementing a website using asp.net MVC. I'm trying assign role to user by clicking into the role. I've tried several ways, unfortunately, I failed.

Controller method

```
[HttpPost,ActionName("AssignUserToRole")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[CustomAuthorize(Roles ="SudoAdmin")]
public ActionResult AssignUserToRole(long userId, long roleId)
{
    new BusinessUser().AddRoleToUser(userId, roleId);

      return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

view

```
 @Html.ActionLink(@r.RoleName, "AssignUserToRole", "Users", new { userId = Model.UserId, roleId = r.RoleId })
```

first I tried Jquery Ajax, but it failed, even though I think it was not a very great idea. However, I still would like to do it with "Ajax"I mean  without refreshing the page.

I hope my question is good enough 
thanks for all of you

Comment: Define "failed". What happens with your `ActionLink`?

Comment: first thanks for replay. it shows  HTTP 404

Comment: What is the url it is trying to load when you click the link ? Is your action method inside `UsersController` ?

Comment: I just would  like to make the action. yes, It is inside the usersController

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the action is set to respond only to POST. That means unless you request it via POST, you'll get a 404, since there's no action that can respond to any other request method.

As a link, it will always make the request via GET. If you employ JavaScript, you can bind to the `click` event and send the request via POST using AJAX, but again, you have to send it as POST. If you use something like `$.get` or `$.ajax` with the method as GET, it won't work.

Ideally, if you intend to hit the action via POST, then you should employ a `form` element in your view. Using CSS, you can style the submit button to look like a link, if that's what you want, but the underlying structure should be a form.